# I want the user to change access db path in the VB client during installation

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm developing a billing application in Visual Basic .Net that uses access db. I need a help with setting the access db path during installation in client machine.

So when I deploy this Visual Basic app in the client's machine, the client should be able to configure the path to the access db with their shared folder. Because, the VB app will be installed in 2 or 3 machines and all instances should use the same access db within their shared folder.

How to do this in a simple way, so it is not too complicating for the client?

Note: The client is happy with access as the volume of transactions is going to be very less. Plus don't want to incur costs with other db options like SQL or Oracle

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer I know, if your developing a multi user app, there are far more robust and better suited database options than Access available you should probably consider

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in several ways. A proven method, using a shortcut and a script to launch the application, is described here:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Gustav. I'm sorry if my question is not clear. I'm developing a billing application in Visual Basic .Net that uses access db. So when I deploy this Visual Basic app in the client's machine, the client should be able to configure the path to the access db with their shared folder. Because, the VB app will be installed in 2 or 3 machines and all instances should use the same access db within their shared folder.

Comment: Oh, that is much different. Then you need to _Publish_ your VB.NET application, at best signing it with a _certificate_. If you know the client well, you may get away with a private certificate. Several methods to implement - we publish to a website at the client, then pass a URL to the users to click, then - when page opens - click a button that runs the full install and finally launches the application. In short: Look up _Publish_ for the full story and the varieties.